# how to put a login form using django

Tags: python, django

After hours and hours of trying, i still cannot seem to make it happen.

basically Im trying to put a login form inside this .post_list.html using django along with the postform. (so there are 2 forms)

this is the views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import PostForm, AuthenticationForm
from .models import Post

def post_detail(request, id=None):
    # instance = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post-list/')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request)
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    postform = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if postform.is_valid():
        instance = postform.save(commit=False)
        print (postform.cleaned_data.get("title"))
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get())
    # else:
        #messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
    queryset = Post.objects.all()#.order_by("-timestamp")
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List",
        "form": postform,
        "form2": form
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
```

and this is the forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
        "title",
        "content"
    ]

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('invalid_login')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

and post_lost.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Username: {{ form.username }} {{ form.username.errors }}<br>
    Password: {{ form.password }} {{ form.password.errors }}<br>
    {{ form.errors }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

<div class='two columns right mgr'>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
       <input class="button-primary" type='submit' value='Create Post' />
    </form>
</div>

<div class='four columns left'>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <!--<img src="..." alt="...">!-->
                        <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{ obj.title }}<small> {{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small></h3>
                        <p>{{ obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
                        <!--  <p><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a> </p>-->
                    </div>
                </div></a>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

could you please help me out? thanks.

Comment: @jape sorry, didn't describe the situation. the postform is workiing , but the login field is not visible on html.

Comment: You're passing `"form": postform,
            "form2": form` into context. Looks like login form is form2. What if you will try to use {{ form2.username }} and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you got this issue because of naming. 
You passing into context the following things:

```
form = AuthenticationForm()
postform = PostForm(request.POST or None)
...
 context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "title": "List",
            "form": postform,
            "form2": form
        }
```

So, when you try to access `form.username` you fail, because in the template `form` is a postform. And postform has no 'usarname' field.

So look like you should try this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Username: {{ form2.username }} {{ form2.username.errors }}<br>
    Password: {{ form2.password }} {{ form2.password.errors }}<br>
    {{ form2.errors }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: you saved my life! totally wasn't aware of it. now it seems to be working just fine in the local server. but for some reason, when i upload this code to the server, the login form is not visible again. could you take a look at this views.py and tell me why it's not working on the server? https://dpaste.de/VpJ7#L7,11,20,24 the post_list.html is same as above.